# Is there a nicer workaround for enable_if bug in CLang (Bug 11723)?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, clang, sfinae

Ideally, we can do something like that with enable_if:

```
#include <type_traits>

namespace detail {
    enum class enabler_t { DUMMY };
}

template<bool B>
using enable_if_u = typename std::enable_if<B, detail::enabler_t>::type;

template<bool B>
using disable_if_u = typename std::enable_if<!B, detail::enabler_t>::type;

template<typename T, enable_if_u<std::is_same<T, int>::value>...>
int a(){return 0;}

template<typename T, disable_if_u<std::is_same<T, int>::value>...>
double a(){return 0.0;}

int main() {
    auto x = a<int>();
}
```

Which is, imho, the nicest way to use it.

However, this doesn't work with Clang, due to [bug 11723](http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=11723).

The workaround that I'm using is using a dummy constexpr variable:

```
namespace detail {
    enum class enabler_t { DUMMY };
    constexpr const enabler_t dummy = enabler_t::DUMMY;
}

//...

template<typename T, enable_if_u<std::is_same<T, int>::value> = detail::dummy>
int a(){return 0;}

template<typename T, disable_if_u<std::is_same<T, int>::value> = detail::dummy>
double a(){return 0.0;}

//...
```

I'm not a huge fan of this workaround I was wondering if there was another workaround to make code working in Clang ? I'm looking for a pure C++ solution, no preprocessor involved.

The example in itself is just here to illustrate the problem, it is not useful at all and there are tons of way to make it better. I just want to find a nicer workaround for the enable_if part.

Comment: All you want to do is call the first `a` when `T = int`, and the second `a` otherwise? Is `T` supposed to be a parameter pack in any of the examples?

Comment: Why don't you just use [a single, defaulted non-type template parameter](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b71a7dc2afd784dc) or tag dispatching?

Comment: @dyp I realize that, I was just wondering if the intent was to switch between two functions having different return types. There are easier ways to do that, as you yourself just demonstrated.

Comment: @Praetorian That's at least how g++ (and my reading of the Standard) interpret it.

Comment: @dyp “Why …” – Because OP’s way is [less syntactic clutter](http://flamingdangerzone.com/cxx11/2012/06/01/almost-static-if.html).

Comment: @KonradRudolph Huh? How is `...` much better than `=T{}`?

Comment: @dyp It’s fundamentally different: it’s one lexeme which is pasted next to the type, almost like part of it, whereas the other is four lexemes and introduces a completely new sub-expression. All this is pure syntactic clutter.

Comment: @Praetorian The example itself is just a stupid example to illustrate the problem.
KonradRudolph: Yes, that is exactly my point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just use a macro instead:

```
#define ENABLE_IF(...) typename std::enable_if<(__VA_ARGS__), detail::enabler_t>::type=detail::enabler_t::DUMMY
```

The macro also has the advantage of avoiding the most vexing parse in C++, since it can always place parenthesis around the boolean expression. If you think the uppercase macro looks ugly, you can use [ZLang](https://github.com/pfultz2/ZLang) to make it cleaner, something like this:

```
#define BW_ENABLE_IF(...) typename std::enable_if<(__VA_ARGS__), detail::enabler_t>::type=detail::enabler_t::DUMMY
#define ZLANG_bw_enable_if (BW_ENABLE_IF)
```

Then you can write the following if you compile with `-DZLANG_NS=bw`:

```
template<typename T, $(enable_if std::is_same<T, int>())>
int a(){return 0;}
```

Comment: Good solution, but I'd rather like to avoid macros if possible, it doesn't feel very C++ like.

Comment: I finally ended up using a macro anyway, so this answer is the best one.